# How to properly apply AM-GM inequality?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

- Find the minimum value of $y = \frac{x^2}{x-9}$ using AM-GM inequality when $x \gt 9$.

**How I tried to solve it:**

Setting $p=x-9$, I did the following:
$$y=\frac{(p+9)^2}{p}$$
$$y=\frac{p^2+18p+81}{p}$$
$$y=p+18+\frac{81}{p}$$
Since $x \gt 9$, $p\gt0$.

Using the AM-GM inequality, we can say,
$$\frac{p+18+\frac{81}{p}}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{p \cdot 18 \cdot \frac{81}{p}}$$
$$y \ge 27\sqrt[3]{2}$$
The actual minimum of $y$ is 36. Now, $y \gt 27\sqrt[3]{2}$ is certainly true, but it is surely not a satisfactory answer. [This link here hints at the proper way to solve the problem.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072465/am-gm-inequality)

**How should the inequality be used *in general* so that it does not cause problems like this? Why is my solution inappropriate?**

Comment: You also need to find a value of $y$ that achieves your proposed minimum. Otherwise you just have an inequality.

Comment: AM/GM is only optimal when all the addends have the same value. It's impossible that $p$, $18$ and $81/p$ are all equal.

Answer (score 1):

One has
$$p+\frac{81}p\ge18$$
by AM/GM, with equality when $p=9$, so
$$p+18+\frac{81}p\ge36,$$
with equality when $p=9$.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM $$\frac{x^2}{x-9}=\frac{x^2-81+81}{x-9}=x-9+\frac{81}{x-9}+18\geq2\sqrt{(x-9)\cdot\frac{81}{x-9}}+18=36.$$
The equality occurs for $x-9=\frac{81}{x-9},$ which says that $36$ is a minimal value.